# Suppose a series $a_n$ is greater than 0 for all positive integer n, and that $\sum \frac {a_n} n$ converges, then does the following also converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was wondering if the following is true.

Suppose a series $a_n$ is greater than 0 for all positive integer n, and that $\sum \frac {a_n}n$ converges, then is $\displaystyle \lim_{m\to \infty}\sum_{n= 1}^m {a_n \over m+n} = 0$?

It seems to be true because if $\sum {a_n\over n}$ converges, then that means that ${a_n\over n }\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$. This means, neglecting $n$, ${a_n \over m+n}$ will also tend to 0, and thus the summation would be equal to 0, but I don't know if this is true.

Comment: Your argument looks wrong. The standard one is to bound $\lim \sum_{n=1}^{m^{1/2}} \frac{a_n}{m+n}$ and $\lim \sum_{n=m^{1/2}}^m \frac{a_n}{m+n}$ separately.

Comment: I'm curious as to how this is solved.

Comment: @reuns: I saw ur comment for this post on another question. Either way, I'm not able to see how $m + n \rightarrow m\sqrt{n}$ helps to show convergence of that series.

Comment: I am also curious for the solve of this problem :))

Comment: A cannon-like [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), but applies immediately.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{m} \frac{a_n}{m+n} \le \sum_{n=1}^{m^{1/2}} \frac{a_n}{m+n}+\sum_{n=m^{1/2}}^m \frac{a_n}{m+n} \le \frac1{\sqrt m}\sum_{n=1}^{m^{1/2}} \frac{a_n}{n}+\sum_{n=m^{1/2}}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$$ the two latter sums $\to 0$ as $m\to \infty$.

Comment: @reuns That is one smart solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon$ be a strictly positive real.

$\sum\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ converges, so: $\displaystyle \ \ \exists N \in \mathbb N^{\star} \ , \ \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty} \dfrac{a_n}{n} \leqslant \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}  $

Then:  $\ \ \displaystyle \forall m \geqslant N \ , \ \ \sum_{n=1}^{m} \dfrac{a_n}{m+n} \leqslant  \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \dfrac{a_n}{m} + \sum_{n=N}^m \dfrac{a_n}{n} \leqslant \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}+\dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n $

Now: $\\ \displaystyle \exists M\geqslant N \ , \ \forall m\geqslant M , \dfrac{1}{m} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n \leqslant \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$

We can conclude that:
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0 \ , \ \exists M \in \mathbb N \ , \ \forall m\geqslant M \ ,\ 0\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{a_n}{n+m} \leqslant \varepsilon    $$

And  $\ \ \displaystyle \lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty} \sum_{n=1}^m\dfrac{a_n}{n+m} = 0$

Comment: I would assume in "Now:" you meant $m\ge M$.

Comment: @user: You are right. I corrected my typo

Answer (score 0):

let $v_n = \frac{a_n}{m+n}$, and $u_n = \frac{a_n}{n}$. Now observe that $\frac{a_n}{m+n} \le \frac{a_n}{2n}$, so by comparison test, we can say that as each term of $v_n$ is smaller or equal to that of $\frac{u_n}{2}$, and as $u_n$ converges, so $v_n$ also converges as $m \to \infty$.

I think this is it.

:)

Comment: No, this isn't it. As you have shown that for two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$: forall $n$, $0 < a_n < b_n$, and $b_n$ converges. This does not imply that the sequence $a_n$ converges.